# properties on groups of order $p^2qr$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I read somewhere that if $|G|=p^2qr$, $H\subseteq G: |H|= p^2q$, $p>q>r$ primes, then if only $H$ is maximal subgroup, then $H$ is Abelian. Is this problem correct? Are there any same properties in groups of order $p^2q^2r$, $p>q>r$?

Comment: What does $\;H\subset H: |H|=p^2q...\;$" mean? The rest of that line isn't clear, either.

Comment: $H$ is subgroup

Comment: I only know such a theorem for groups with order $pq$, $p<q$ primes, but perhaps it can be extended to the situation, we have here. But there was an additional restriction, which I do not remember to $100\%$. I think it was : $p$ does not divide $q-1$.

Comment: By "if only $H$ is maximal subgroup", do you mean "if $H$ is the only proper subgroup whose order is $\ge p^2q$?

Comment: The language is rather confusing...

Comment: A group of order $\;p^2q\;$ is a group of order $\;p^2qr\;,\;\;p>q>r\;$ primes, is *always* maximal.

Comment: I think $H$ is only subgroup with maximal size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain that I'm interpreting your question correctly, so this may be rubbish.  I *think* you are asking whether $H$ must be abelian if $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order $p^2q$, where $G$ has order $p^2qr$ with $p,q,r$ primes and $p>q>r$.

In this case, the answer is "no".  Take the non-abelian group $H$ of order $75 = 5^23$ (so $p=5$ and $q=3$), and put $G = H\times C_2$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order $2$ (so $r=2$). Then $H$ is the only subgroup of order $75$ in $G$, but of course, $H$ is *not* abelian by construction.